# Error when confirming registration using flask-security

Tags: python, flask, flask-security

I'm using flask-security to handle user registration, login, etc. I'm facing a problem when registering a new user using the default flask-security views.

### EDIT

I managed to advance a little on solving the problem. The initial problem was that I wasn't providing a load_user callback. Now I'm doing it:

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.objects.get(id=user_id)
```

Problem is that the confirmation url/view seems to use an AnonymousUser and so, the query filter does not match the correct user. Any clues guys?

### Original

I'm able to provide user mail and password in the registration view, I successfully receive a confirmation e-mail (the default template provided by flask-security) but when I try to confirm the account clicking on the mail confirmation link I get the following attribute error:

```
AttributeError: 'AnonymousUserMixin' object has no attribute 'roles'
```

Here is the full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/infante/PycharmProjects/venvs/wp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/infante/PycharmProjects/venvs/wp/lib/python2.7/site-  packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/home/infante/PycharmProjects/venvs/wp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/infante/PycharmProjects/venvs/wp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/infante/PycharmProjects/venvs/wp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/infante/PycharmProjects/venvs/wp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/infante/PycharmProjects/venvs/wp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/infante/PycharmProjects/venvs/wp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/infante/PycharmProjects/venvs/wp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_security/views.py", line 226, in confirm_email
    logout_user()
  File "/home/infante/PycharmProjects/venvs/wp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_security/utils.py", line 92, in logout_user
    identity=AnonymousIdentity())
  File "/home/infante/PycharmProjects/venvs/wp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/blinker/base.py", line 267, in send
    for receiver in self.receivers_for(sender)]
  File "/home/infante/PycharmProjects/venvs/wp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_principal.py", line 469, in _on_identity_changed
    self.set_identity(identity)
  File "/home/infante/PycharmProjects/venvs/wp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_principal.py", line 418, in set_identity
    self._set_thread_identity(identity)
  File "/home/infante/PycharmProjects/venvs/wp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_principal.py", line 463, in _set_thread_identity
    identity=identity)
  File "/home/infante/PycharmProjects/venvs/wp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/blinker/base.py", line 267, in send
    for receiver in self.receivers_for(sender)]
  File "/home/infante/PycharmProjects/venvs/wp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_security/core.py", line 217, in _on_identity_loaded
    for role in current_user.roles:
  File "/home/infante/PycharmProjects/venvs/wp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 338, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
AttributeError: 'AnonymousUserMixin' object has no attribute 'roles'
```

Here is my app configuration:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.security import MongoEngineUserDatastore, Security
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask_mail import Mail

from wpapp.models import db, User, Role
from wpapp.views import frontend
from wpapp.configs import CONFS


login_manager = LoginManager()
app = Flask(__name__)

app.config["MONGODB_SETTINGS"] = CONFS['MONGODB_SETTINGS']
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = CONFS['SECRET_KEY']
app.config['SECURITY_PASSWORD_HASH'] = CONFS['SECURITY_PASSWORD_HASH']
app.config['SECURITY_PASSWORD_SALT'] = CONFS['SECURITY_PASSWORD_SALT']
app.config['SECURITY_REGISTERABLE'] = CONFS['SECURITY_REGISTERABLE']
app.config['SECURITY_CONFIRMABLE'] = CONFS['SECURITY_CONFIRMABLE']
app.config['SECURITY_RECOVERABLE'] = CONFS['SECURITY_RECOVERABLE']
app.config['SECURITY_REGISTER_URL'] = CONFS['SECURITY_REGISTER_URL']
app.config['MAIL_SERVER'] = CONFS['MAIL_SERVER']
app.config['MAIL_PORT'] = CONFS['MAIL_PORT']
app.config['MAIL_USE_SSL'] = CONFS['MAIL_USE_SSL']
app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'] = CONFS['MAIL_USERNAME']
app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD'] = CONFS['MAIL_PASSWORD']

mail = Mail(app)
app.register_blueprint(frontend)

db.init_app(app)

user_datastore = MongoEngineUserDatastore(db, User, Role)
security = Security(app, user_datastore)

login_manager.init_app(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

And here are my models definitions (I'm using mongodb):

```
from flask.ext.mongoengine import MongoEngine
from flask.ext.security import UserMixin, RoleMixin

db = MongoEngine()

class Role(db.Document, RoleMixin):

    name = db.StringField(verbose_name=u"Nome",
                          help_text=u"Inserir um nome para identificação do Papel.",
                          max_length=50,
                          required=True,
                          unique=True)

    description = db.StringField(verbose_name=u"Descrição",
                                 help_text=u"Inserir descrição sucinta sobre o Papel.",
                                 max_length=255)


class User(db.Document, UserMixin):

    email = db.StringField(verbose_name=u"E-mail",
                           help_text=u"Cadastrar um e-mail válido.",
                           max_length=255,
                           required=True,
                           unique=True)

    password = db.StringField(verbose_name=u"Senha",
                              help_text=u"Cadastrar sua senha para acesso.",
                              required=True,
                              max_length=255)

    active = db.BooleanField(verbose_name=u"Ativo",
                             help_text=u"Indica se o usuário está ativo no sistema.",
                             default=True)

    confirmed_at = db.DateTimeField(verbose_name=u"Confirmação",
                                    help_text=u"Horário de confirmação do usuário")

    roles = db.ListField(db.ReferenceField(Role),
                         verbose_name=u"Papéis",
                         help_text=u"Atribuir papéis ao usuário.",
                         default=[])
```

Does anyone have a clue on what may the problem be?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks deadbeef404, pretty much nailed it. I would have commented on your answer, but I don't have any rep.

Actually flask login uses it's own AnonymousUserMixin class. The following snippet shows how to override it with flask security's AnonymousUser class.

```
login_manager = LoginManager()
from flask.ext.security import AnonymousUser
login_manager.anonymous_user = AnonymousUser
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your exact problem is but it seems that flask principal is trying to use the `AnonymousUser` (the identity in memory when no one is logged in) like an authenticated user. An `AnonymousUser` doesn't have a `roles` attribute so when it tries to access it, it throws an Exception.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Do you have any guess on how to fix it?

Comment: I think I ran into this or a very similar problem a while ago but unfortunately I don't remember much about it. I ran into so many of these things where I had to dig through the source code of flask/flask-security/flask-principal etc. The only option is really to go digging yourself and try to figure out what's happening. This is one of the reasons I still prefer Django over flask; the Django user systems are all wrapped up nicely and work for basic functionality.

Comment: Thanks!
I'm managing to dig around. Problem seems to be that I should set the flask-login anonymous user to be flask-security anonymous user and provide a custom load_user function. I'm trying to do this. Thanks again for your time ad help!